# Check if lines in a file only starts with "@" or "-"

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline

I will read a file with `BufferedReader()` and `readLine()`.
The Result will be written in an `ArrayList<String>`.

I will check every line in the .txt if starts with "@" or with "–". 
If not `InvalidFormatException` should be thrown.

```
for(String s:Data) {
    if (!s.startsWith("@") || !s.startsWith("-"))
        throw new InvalidFormatException("Invalid Format");
}
```

my .txt looks like:

```
@1.2.1
- new feature @1.2.0
- new picture
```

so it should only work if "@" or "-" ist the beginning character of a line

```
@1.2.1
- new feature 
new picture
```

this example should throw an Exception

I get every time I try it the Exception.

Are there any hidden Characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with the use of RegEx

```
for(String s:Data) {
            if (s.matches("[^@-].*$"))
                throw new InvalidFormatException("wrong Format");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong, you want to throw `Exception` if first character is not `'@'` **and** it is not `'-'`. Use this:

```
if (!s.startsWith("@") && !s.startsWith("-"))
    throw new InvalidFormatException("Invalid Format");
```

Btw if you only test the first character, you can do just that: test the first character and not check string match (in this case you also have to check if there is a first character: not empty):

```
if (s.isEmpty() || (s.charAt(0) != '@' && s.charAt(0) != '-'))
    throw new InvalidFormatException("Invalid Format");
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost.  Your condition is "if doesn't start with `@` OR doesn't start with `-`".

Try using `&&` (and) instead:

```
if (!s.startsWith("@") && !s.startsWith("-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The boolean operator you are using is `OR`.

Your condition will check whether it doesn't start with the first character, `OR` if it doesn't start with the second.

Since you are checking for something that doesn't start with either, you must use `AND`.

Replace your code with:

```
if (!s.startsWith("@") && !s.startsWith("-"))
```